# html form calls on a php file.. but variables are not read

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple html file with the code below. It calls submitform.php. But nothing gets displayed. Any ideas?

```
<html>
<body>
<form action=submitform.php method=GET>

First Name: <input type=text name=first_name size=25 maxlength=25>

Last Name: <input type=text name=last_name size=25 maxlength=25>
<p>
<input type=submit>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php code in submitform.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 


print ($first_name);
echo $first_name;

print (" ");

print ($last_name);

print ("<p>");

print ("Thanks for submitting your name.");

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
print ($first_name);
```

Use

```
print ($_GET['first_name']);
```

You are using the GET method of the form.

However, if you still want to use:

```
print ($first_name);
```

Then on top of your php file place this line:

```
extract($_GET);
```

Comment: beware of extract function its dangerous to use extract().

Answer (score 0):

You could also set "register_globals on" in your php.ini file to have access to both GET and POST variables w/o $_GET[] and extract().